# Richfaces Calendar with year part in 20th or 21st century

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using Richfaces(3.3.1) Calendar component as a date picker and the date field editing is also enabled. I want to restrict the user from manually entering any date before 20th century or after 21st century - basically the first two characters of the year part should be '19' or '20'. Is there an out of box way to do it, or do I need to customize Richfaces Calendar component? I do not want to do this in the validator as different dates have different validators and in that case I'll have duplicate code and will have to change all date controls.

Here the code snippet:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{selectedClaim.dateOfLoss}" required="true"
       label="Date of loss" locale="en/US" popup="true"
       datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" enableManualInput="true"
       cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px"
       inputSize="10" rendered="#{selectedClaim.id == 0}"
       validator="#{claimUtils.checkEntryDate}">
</rich:calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement a CalendarDataModel and assign it as dataModel for the calendar. You can disable CalendarDataItem if it doesn't match your condition.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.intercept.BypassInterceptors;
import org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModel;
import org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModelItem;

@Name("richCalendarDataModel")
@BypassInterceptors
public class RichCalendarDataModel implements CalendarDataModel {


    public CalendarDataModelItem[] getData(Date[] arg0) {
        RichCalendarDataItem[] date = new RichCalendarDataItem[arg0.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (Date dd : arg0) {
            RichCalendarDataItem tmp = new RichCalendarDataItem(dd, enable_disableDate(dd));
            date[i] = tmp;
            i++;
        }

        return date;
    }

    private boolean enable_disableDate(Date dd) {
        if (!isSunday(dd))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public Object getToolTip(Date arg0) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

CalendarDataModelItem:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModelItem;

public class RichCalendarDataItem implements CalendarDataModelItem {

private Date data;

private boolean enabled;

public RichCalendarDataItem(Date dd, boolean en) {
    data = dd;
    enabled = en;
}

public int getDay() {
    return 0;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getStyleClass() {
    return null;
}

public Object getToolTip() {
    return null;
}

public boolean hasToolTip() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```

}